# Error when creating a custom ErrorDocument 404 in apache

Tags: debian, web-server, apache-2.2

I have a virtual server running apache2 on debian. I would like to create a default 404 error message in the apache2.conf for all my websites.

`ErrorDocument 404 "/var/www/site/public/404.html"`

The error I get after restarting apache is: `Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

It works if I enter the URL although I dont want the page to redirect only use a default 404.html page.

Comment: +1 for humorous irony

Comment: I've never seen a 404 loop

Comment: I don't know whether to be happy with the vote ups or embarrassed it was a daft question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't use the full path in ErrorDocument. Its relative to your htdocs root

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument

if your root is /var/www/site/public/

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

You can also do a full url

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/404.html
```

**EDIT**

You can do this for each vhost then

```
Alias /404 /full/path/to/404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Comment: Thank you, although is there anyway to do this without having to upload 404.html to each vhost website? Maybe I could add an alias for the 404.html, is this the best way?

Comment: edited my answer for an alias in there